# SOAP request XML

Tags: java, javascript

```
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://service.project-development-site.de/soap.php",true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {

    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

      // http://www.terracoder.com convert XML to JSON 
      var json = XMLObjectifier.xmlToJSON(xmlhttp.responseXML);
      var result = json.Body[0].GetQuoteResponse[0].GetQuoteResult[0].Text;
      // Result text is escaped XML string, convert string to XML object then convert to JSON object
      json = XMLObjectifier.xmlToJSON(XMLObjectifier.textToXML(result));
      alert(symbol + ' Stock Quote: $' + json.Stock[0].Last[0].Text); 
     }
    }
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://service.project-development-site.de/soap.php");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
     '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">' + 
        '<soapenv:Header/>'+
           '<soapenv:Body>'+
              '<tem:loginUserSoapInPart>'+
                 '<tem:userName>user</tem:userName>'+
                 '<tem:passWord>pwd</tem:passWord>'+
                 '<tem:accesToken>acktoken</tem:accesToken>'+
              '</tem:loginUserSoapInPart>'+
           '</soapenv:Body>'+
        '</soapenv:Envelope>';
    xmlhttp.send(xml);
```

I have used this code with the soap  request xml but it is not giving me response.i am checking it in alert but i am getting empty alert message.

Comment: Is your code on the same URL? It has to be this way.

Comment: Have you checked the response in the debugger (browser). Also, fiddler2 can be a good utility to debug (www.fiddler2.com).

Comment: yes i have checked it in fiddler2 it works gives me response

Comment: I see 2 alert statements. Which one are you referring to? If you are getting response, then first alert should display the value. If the problem is with the second alert then that has to do with the JSON data (particulary your model)

Comment: first alert is not displaying it is showing empty